# Passing variables to a subprocess call

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to pass my variables from `raw_input` to my subprocess command. I am new to Python. Any help would he appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

print "\nWhat user name"
username = str(raw_input('username: '))
print "\nWhat is the user id"
userid = int(raw_input('Enter user id: '))
print "\nWhat is the user\'s primary group?"
primarygroup = int(raw_input('Enter group: '))
print "\nWhat is the user\'s secondary group?"
secondarygroup = int(raw_input('Enter group: '))

subprocess.call(['useradd' '-m' '-g' _primarygroup '-G' _secondarygroup '-u' _userid _username])

print"\nThe user has been added"
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  Please be specific.

Comment: Really old but I'll note that, for example, the primary group was read into `primarygroup` but then attempted to be accessed via `_primarygroup`.

Answer (score 40):

Try separating the values with commas:

```
subprocess.call(['useradd', '-m', '-g', _primarygroup, '-G', _secondarygroup, '-u', _userid, _username])
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call - It takes an array where the first argument is the program and all other arguments are passed as arguments to the program.

Also don't forget to check the return value of the function for a zero return code which means "success" unless it doesn't matter for your script if the user was added successfully or not.

Comment: I am trying to pass the value given from raw_input to my subprocess call.

Answer (score 8):

Try to add commas between your list items:

```
subprocess.call(['useradd', '-m', '-g', _primarygroup, '-G', _secondarygroup, \
                 '-u' ,_userid, _username])
```

`subprocess.call` takes the same arguments as [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> `args` should be a string, or a **sequence** of program arguments.

---

*Edit*

To turn all your arguments into strings at once you could you a list comprehension:

```
args = ['useradd', '-m', '-g', _primarygroup, '-G', _secondarygroup, \
        '-u' ,_userid, _username]
str_args = [ str(x) for x in args ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the values for _primarygroup, _secondarygroup, and _username have to be integers. IE: useradd -g 501 -503 -u 501

Comment: Maybe your problem is with the shell. Arguments to programs and scripts can only ever be passed as strings (eg. the string '501' is passed instead of integer 501). It is up the called process to parse these strings into the correct format.

Comment: You can turn your arguments into strings before passing them to `call`; see my edit.

Comment: Or just `subprocess.check_call(['useradd', '-m', '-g', str(_primarygroup), '-G', str(_secondarygroup), '-u', str(_userid)])`

Answer (score 4):

You can create the arg string first and then just past this variable to the subprocess.call. For example:

```
projects_csv_fn = 'projects_csv_2.csv'
prjects_json_fn = 'projects.json'

args ='python json_to_csv.py id ' + prjects_json_fn + ' ' + projects_csv_fn

subprocess.call(args, shell=True)
```

Comment: If someone tries to upload a project CSV named `$(rm -rf ~).csv`, running this code means someone'll have a really bad day.

Comment: There are several other [reasons to avoid `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795190/passing-variables-to-a-subprocess-call) and gluing strings together so that the shell needs to split them apart again is obviously just wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call(['useradd', '-m','-g', _primarygroup, '-G', _secondarygroup, '-u', _userid, _username])
```

Pass a `list` to `subprocess.call`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just using *'xxx{0}'.format(variable)* ?
  [see link1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#id17)  [or link2](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html)

```
subprocess.run(['useradd', '-m', '-g {0}'.format(_primarygroup), '-G {0}'.format(_secondarygroup), '-u {0}'.format(_userid)], capture_output=True)
```

or

```
subprocess.call(['useradd', '-m', '-g {0}'.format(_primarygroup), '-G {0}'.format(_secondarygroup), '-u {0}'.format(_userid)])
```

just worked fine to me

Comment: This is wrong; `'-g'` and the group name need to be separate strings, and similarly for `'-G'` and `'-u'`. Try `subprocess.check_call(['useradd', '-m', '-g', _primarygroup, '-G', _secondarygroup, '-u', _userid])`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use f-strings.

```
 import subprocess

 site = 'google.com'
 subprocess.run(['nslookup', f'{site}'])
```

Comment: `f'{site}'` is just a silly way to say `site` if `site` is already a string.

Comment: @tripleee `f"{site}"` calls the `__format__` specifier which can also convert non strings into strings, and change the formatting of different things like integers.

Comment: Of course; that's why it's (more) silly specifically if the value is already a string. For just converting a value into a string, `str(site)` would be clearer and more idiomatic.