# Variable arguments for Subprocess call method in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to pass variables to call method (subprocess) as below:

```
def check(number):
    nodes = ["10.0.0.1","10.0.0.2"]
    nr=number
    for node in nodes:
        output=call(["ssh","-F","/home/config","user@",_node,","some_command",_nr])
        print output
```

The error when this function "check" is called is below:

```
NameError: global name '_node' is not defined
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Why are you passing in _node & _nr? Shouldn't you be passing in node & nr?

Comment: Your problem is a lot more fundamental than anything to do with `subprocess`.  Start smaller: try building up the list that you intend to pass to `call`,  and verify that that list looks the way you think it should look before proceeding.  You'll find you probably need to learn a few things about working with strings (maybe look for tutorials on concatenating and formatting strings in Python).\

Comment: `user@node` would have to be one argument, or use `"-u", user, node` to specify the user and remote host separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never define `_node`. You define `node` and `nodes` but never `_node`. I also don't see where you define `_nr`.

Comment: I was referring to the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795190/pass-variable-to-subprocess-call-in-python when writing the code! thank you :)

Comment: Be very careful when doing something like that :).