# Python error in subprocess command for ffprobe

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess, ffprobe

I am trying to use python for ffprobe. but i am getting error.

i wish to create a file which will have all the data

```
videofile=raw_input('What is the file path?')
cmd = ['ffprobe', '-i', 'videofile', '>' 'file.txt']
response = subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

but i am getting error

```
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ffprobe', '-i', 'videofile', '>file.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: videofile is a variable. You are quoting it as a string. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795190/pass-variable-to-subprocess-call-in-python).

Comment: i tried to do this                                                                                                  str_args = [ str(x) for x in cmd ]response = subprocess.check_output(str_args, 
                shell=True,
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)                                                  but still the same error

Comment: When using `shell=True`, you should pass a command-line string instead of a list. For example: `cmd = 'ffprobe -i "%s" > file.txt' % videofile`. Windows always uses a command-line string. Under the hood, `subprocess.list2cmdline` converts a list to a string using the MSVC parsing rules, but cmd.exe doesn't follow these rules. You also need to use a string on POSIX systems, which ensures the arguments are passed to the command rather than the shell.

Comment: if you don't understand the difference between `videofile` and `'videofile'` in Python then you should [step back and learn the basics](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) otherwise you'll spend all the time fixing trivial preventable errors.