# Passing python variables into powershell

Tags: python, powershell

Looking for help with passing python variables into powershell.

Using the subprocess.call method to open powershell and run a powershell script that echos the variables from python I receive a not recognized error . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example python code:

```
row = ['hello' , 'world']
first = row[0]
second = row[1]
subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
". \"./testShell2\";", "&variables(first, second)"])
```

Example powershell:

```
ECHO $first
ECHO $second
```

Error recieved

The term 'first' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variable to subprocess call in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795190/pass-variable-to-subprocess-call-in-python)

Comment: `"&variables(first, second)"` --> `"&variables {0} {1}".format(first, second)`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using python instead of powershell to complete project. Thank you